# Is the maximum video length of the Sony A6000 30 minutes?

Tags: video, sony-nex, hd-video

I read [a comment about the A6000 on B&H's website](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=NavBar&A=getItemDetail&Q=&sku=1029860&is=REG&si=rev&mode=edu#costumerReview) and @BradZChef (commentor) said the **maximum video length of Sony A6000 is just 30 minutes**. I took a look at [the Sony A6000 specifications](http://store.sony.com/a6000-mirrorless-camera-zid27-ILCE6000//cat-27-catid-All-Alpha-a6000-Cameras?vva_ColorCode=BC008&_t=pfm=category) BUT I didn't find any information mentioning limited video length on the A6000. I also googled for it but I didn't find any resources. Anyone have any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page 36 of the [manual](http://support.sony-asia.com.edgesuite.net/consumer/IM/4532055111.pdf).

> The table below shows the approximate maximum recording times. These
>   are the total times for all movie files. Continuous shooting is
>   possible for approximately 29 minutes (a product specification limit).
>   The maximum continuous recording time of an MP4 (12M) format movie is
>   about 20 minutes (limited by the 2 GB file size restriction).

Comment: Slightly confused, is the 2GB file size restriction limited to the mp4 format, I would think this would apply even if you use AVCHD, am I correct in assuming this?

Comment: @eLouai - I have 4gb MP4 files on my camera (file system limit).  On a file system supporting larger file sizes, they can be much larger.  Not sure why that one is limited to 2GB, I just know that's what the manual says.

Answer (score 6):

More generally, you'll find that most cameras which are primarily stills cameras will be limited to 30 minutes of video. This is due to EU regulations which mean that anything which can record longer than 30 minutes is a "video camera" and attracts a higher rate of duty. Panasonic are a notable exception to this in that they produce separate EU and non-EU models, with only the EU model being limited.

Comment: While generally find this, but it isn't the case on every camera.  Some manufacturers only shorted the recording length for the devices they send to Europe.  It is true in the majority of cases, but not true on every camera.

Comment: Do you have an example of a camera for which only the European version is crippled in this way?

Comment: Panasonic GH2's non EU models.  Doing some more digging, it seems that Panasonic/Lumix may be the only major manufacturer to make non-EU versions.